# Sign of an integral of a product function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a$ and $b$ be any two real numbers and $f$, $g$ $\in$ ${C}[a, b]$. If $\int_a^b f > 0 $ and $\int_a^b g < 0$, can we say that $\int_a^b fg <0$?

Answer (score 2):

$\int_{-1}^1(x+1/2)dx=1$ and $\int_{-1}^1(x-1/2)dx=-1$ while $\int_{-1}^1(x+1/2)(x-1/2)dx=2/3-1/2\gt 0$

Comment: Than you marwalix

Comment: You are welcome